# Card.io does not scan expiry date in android

Tags: card.io

I'm trying to scan my master-card  using Android Card.io SDK. Scanner scan the card number properly but it is failing to read expiry date. I have to to enter the date manually.

Comment: Please elaborate your question with your code you have tried.

Answer (score 3):

Dave from card.io here.

@Pankaj please see [this github issue](https://github.com/card-io/card.io-iOS-SDK/issues/92) for an ongoing discussion regarding the scanning of expiry dates. As you will read there, this is a work in progress; some cards scan successfully, but many other cards do not.